# HTML and PHP How to make sure <p> contents does not wrap onto third line?

Tags: php, html

consider the following code:

```
<?php 


                $fetchlast = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM posts)");
                $lastrow = mysql_fetch_row($fetchlast);
                $lastid = $lastrow[6];

                for ($i=1; $i <= $lastid; $i++) { 

                    $currentname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=$i");

                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($currentname)) {
                        $title = $row[0];
                        $desc = $row[13];
                        $ID = $row[6];
                        $views = $row[3];

                        $title2 = rtrim($title);
                        $donetitle = str_replace(" ", "-", $title2);
                        $url = "articles/".$ID."/".$donetitle."";

                        $donetitle = strlen($title) > 40 ? substr($title,0,60)."..." : $title;
                        $donedesc = '';

                        if(strlen($desc) > 150) {
                            $donedesc = explode( "\n", wordwrap( $desc, 150));
                            $donedesc1 = $donedesc[0] . '...';

                        }else{
                            $donedesc1 = $desc;

                        }

                        $finviews = number_format($views, 0, '.', ',');

                        echo "<div id = \"feature\">
                               <img src=\"img/tempsmall.jpg\" alt = \"article thumbnail\" />
                              </div>
                                <div id = \"feature2\">
                                    <a href= \"$url\" id = \"titletext\" alt = \"8 bit computer input system \">$donetitle</a>
                                     <p id=\"resultp\">$donedesc1</p>
                                     <b id=\"resultview\">$finviews views</b> 
                                </div>
                              <div id = \"border\"></div>";

                    }

                }
?>
```

The above code outputs a series of search results. Each result has a discription. I only want the description to take up two lines, I dont want it to wrap onto the third. So i though limiting the amount of characters to 150 would work but no that does not fully work. The problem is as follow: if you have a description composed of 150 'f's, it would be alot shorter than a description composed of 150 'D's because the 'f's are thinner. Without switching to a different font how can I remove a part of the string to make the description fit the two lines and not go onto the third? Thanks.

Comment: Define "line".  What happens when the user narrows their browser?  This looks like a job for client-side functionality, not server-side.

Comment: then the user has to scroll

Comment: So this is for an absolute fixed width?  What is that width and where/how do you define it?  What if the user changes the zoom level on the browser?  Or has different local font settings than you expect?  Any way you look at this, it's for client-side code to determine.  And even then, the return on investment seems small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would accomplish this with `CSS` by setting your `line-height` and then a `max-height` to 2x your `line-height` which will be 2 lines.

```
.truncate {
  line-height: 25px;
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0xc09f6p/